# Redirect to another page when ok clicked in confirm box

Tags: javascript

```
<a href ='create.php?monitor_id=$id' 
  onclick=if(confirm('really?')) return true; else return false;>
<center>DELETE</center></a>
```

I want to redirect my page to create.php when the user clicks ok in the confirm box, but this won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Be careful if the page is accessible from the public: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/49RjRsQKIw4

Comment: So, did your find your solution here? If so accept an answer.

Comment: if `$id` is a `php` variable you should use the php tags right? like:
`<a href = '<?php echo "create.php?monitor_id=$id" ?>'`

Answer (score 1):

Use **`double quotes`** to wrap your **`onclick()`**

```
onclick="if
        ^
```

**Modified Code**

```
<a href ='create.php?monitor_id=$id' onclick="if(confirm('really?')) return true; else return false;"><center>DELETE</center></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes `"` in both attributes (`href, onclick`);

otherwise your `$id` get's not parsed in `href`; And the `onclick` does not work correctly without double quotes.

```
<a href="create.php?monitor_id=<?php echo $id; ?>" 
  onclick="if(confirm('really?')) return true; else return false;">
<center>DELETE</center></a>
```

Comment: @TomSarduy yeah, right. Added them. Thank you. (It's because I never have this sh*t inline php/html screw up thingy.)

Answer (score 0):

> As you have specific url to redirect on click you have to write as follow

```
<a href ='create.php?monitor_id=$id' 
  onclick="doConfirm()">
<center>DELETE</center></a>

<script tyle="text/javascript">
    function doConfirm() {
         if(confirm('really?')) {
             window.location.href = "create.php?monitor_id=$id";
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
    }
</script>
```